# Json Deserialise Issue

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

When attempting to Deserialize this property in my class im getting the following error message :-

> Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartArray. Path '['When
>   opening the account which of these applied?']', line 53, position 58.

JSON Snippet

```
"When opening the account which of these applied?": [
            "option1",
            "option2",
            "option3",
            "option4"
        ]
```

The C# Property :-

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "When opening the account which of these applied?")]
public string Whenopeningtheaccountwhichoftheseapplied { get; set; }
```

Its the only property that throws an errors.

Im Deserialising using the following statement :--

```
var submission = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FormStackSubmission>(json);
```

Any Ideas as to why its doing this?

Comment: Your JSON is missing curly braces.

Comment: Its a snippet, not teh full JSON string

Comment: I know, but for the sake of creating a self-contained question you should still make it valid JSON.

Comment: 40 chars long variable name, are you trying to make it to the Guiness World Book? ;)

Comment: I used Json.Net paste JSON as classes for those property names ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a single item but an array. If you update your class as below it should work:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "When opening the account which of these applied?")]
public List<string> Whenopeningtheaccountwhichoftheseapplied { get; set; }
```